# EL variables not working in WAS 8

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, websphere-8

I use websphere 8 and RAD 8 and this scriptlet output the correct value:

`<%= ansokanInfo.getPSystem() %>`

But using EL it outputs nothing:

`${ansokanInfo.PSystem}`

I can write anything between the `${` and `}` and it won't render. What am I doing wrong? what should be done to enable EL expressions? This is not working either:

`<c:out value="${ansokanInfo.PSystem}" />`

But this is working:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5" >     <c:out value="${i}" />    </c:forEach>
```

My web.xml starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Scriptlets* and EL do not share the same variable scope. *Scriptlet* variables are declared in JSP body, while EL variables are supposed to be set as an attribute of the page, request, session or application scope.

So, to make the `ansokanInfo` available in EL, you need to set it in one of those scopes. Assuming that it represents request scoped data, do so:

```
request.setAttribute("ansokanInfo", ansokanInfo);
```

You could do that in a *scriptlet* before the first EL evaluation of this variable ever. But more sensible would be to do that in a preprocessing servlet.

To learn and understand the concepts properly, check our wiki pages on the mandatory subjects:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)